# How to make Data::Printer show stringified values in internals?

Tags: perl, formatting, ddp

I have some complex object structures, and I use Data::Printer to inspect them.  One case where it's not helpful enough is this: when an object (container) has a field that's another object (child), the child shows up in DDP's output only as class name.  I wish to also see the stringified value of the child.

Let's have an example:

```
{
    package Child;
    use Moo;

    use overload '""' => "stringify";

    has 'value', is => 'ro';

    sub stringify {
        my $self = shift;
        return "<Child:" . $self->value . ">";
    }

}

{
    package Container;
    use Moo;

    has 'child', is => 'ro';
}

my $child_x = Child->new(value => 'x');
print "stringified child x: $child_x\n";

my $child_y = Child->new(value => 'y');
print "stringified child y: $child_y\n";

my $container_x = Container->new(child => $child_x);
my $container_y = Container->new(child => $child_y);

use DDP;
print "ddp x: " . p($container_x) . "\n";
print "ddp y: " . p($container_y) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
stringified child x: <Child:x>
stringified child y: <Child:y>
ddp x: Container  {
    Parents       Moo::Object
    public methods (2) : child, new
    private methods (0)
    internals: {
        child   Child                  # <- note this
    }
}
ddp y: Container  {
    Parents       Moo::Object
    public methods (2) : child, new
    private methods (0)
    internals: {
        child   Child                  # <- and this
    }
}
```

As you see, the children are indistinguishable in the output.  I'd like to see the stringification in that place, either in addition to or instead of the class name.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the Data::Printer docs](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aPrinter#FILTERS),

> Data::Printer offers you the ability to use filters to override any
>   kind of data display. The filters are placed on a hash, where keys are
>   the types - or class names - and values are anonymous subs that
>   receive two arguments: the item itself as first parameter, and the
>   properties hashref (in case your filter wants to read from it). This
>   lets you quickly override the way Data::Printer handles and displays
>   data types and, in particular, objects.

Comment: Thank you for putting me on the right track.  I've noticed this paragraph too but thought for some reason it would be difficult to use this feature, which is not.  I'll post the answer with an example for posterity.

Answer (score 2):

As Dave pointed out, we can define the filter when importing Data::Printer:

```
use DDP filters => {
    'Child' => sub { "$_[0]" }
};
```

And even better way would be to use the [_data_printer](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aPrinter#MAKING-YOUR-CLASSES-DDP-AWARE-WITHOUT-ADDING-ANY-DEPS) feature (because it's a pain to type out the filters definition every time I import DDP):

```
{
    package Child;
    ...

    sub _data_printer {
        my $self = shift;
        return "$self";
    }
}
```

Both ways display the stringified value in internals:

```
ddp x: Container  {
    Parents       Moo::Object
    public methods (2) : child, new
    private methods (0)
    internals: {
        child   <Child:x>
    }
}
```

Comment: _data_printer was actually what I went looking for in the docs first, but I've never actually used it and wasn't sure whether it would apply to child objects or only the parent. Now I know - thanks!